# Edit files inside zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to work with (i.e. edit, create, delete...) files such as `.docx1`, and `.xlsx` inside a zip file without unzipping the file in Python?

Comment: Read this module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html)

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to work (intelligent) with a file without reading it first. Unzipping == reading.

Comment: -1?  Is there a way to work (i.e. edit, create, delete...) with files without reading the file? Yes, one can create a new file, delete an old file, but not edit. The same with zip file: it is just another file system. Python library allows adding a new file to zip fille, but I don't see any delete in documentation.